# Is there any way to linearize $x-x^2\leq 0$?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve an optimization problem. 
The objective function and all constraints of this problem are linear except $x-x^2\leq 0$. 
Is there any way to linearize $x-x^2\leq 0$, where $x$ is a continuous variable? 
Note that $x$ is not in the objective function.
It should be noted that the original problem is a binary linear problem, to relax this problem, I add constraint $x-x^2\leq 0$  to the problem where $0\leq x \leq 1$. Constraint $x-x^2\leq 0$ forces $x$ to $0$ or $1$, but this constraint converts problem to a non-linear problem.

Comment: Factor $x-x^2$ as $x(1-x)$ and work in cases. When is the product of two numbers zero or negative?

Comment: So you have a binary linear program but you are trying to convert it to a continuous, nonlinear problem by converting $x \in \{0,1\}$ to $0 \le x \le 1$ and $x(1-x) \le 0$; is that right? This is mathematically OK, but there is no way to linearize it. (Proof: If you could, then every binary IP could be converted to an equivalent LP, which is polynomially solvable, hence P = NP!) Is there a particular reason you are using this approach rather than just solving the IP directly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The complexity of ILP is high (ILP is NP-hard). So, I want to relax this problem, but relaxation is not meaningful for the variables. Accordingly, I search for a way that the solution of relaxed problem is binary.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x-x^2=x(1-x)\le 0,$ then $x$ and $1-x$ cannot have the same sign. Thus, one of them must be $0,$ or else they must have opposite signs. The zero case you've already determined as $x=0$ or $x=1.$ But how could they have opposite signs? Well, if $x<0,$ then $-x>0,$ so $1-x>0,$ so that works out fine. Otherwise, we need $1-x<0,$ in which case $1<x,$ and so $x>0,$ so that works out fine. Thus, the constraint can be rewritten as $$x\le 0\textrm{ or }x\ge 1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this makes my problem infeasible.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! You can't deal with it in two separate cases, one with the constraint $x\le0,$ the other with the constraint $x\ge1$?

Comment: Since I have the constraint $0\leq x\leq 1$, adding either $x\leq 0$ or $x\geq 1$ makes the problem infeasible.

Comment: Where did the constraint $0\le x\le 1$ come from? Rereading your post, it seems like you concluded it from $x-x^2\le0$ (which would be an incorrect conclusion), but perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you. If we have $0\leq x\leq 1$, constraint $x-x^2\leq 0$ forces to  $x=1$ or $x=0$.